# data format: pymongo insert of array

Tags: python, formatting, pymongo

I have an object I wish to store in mongo. Using PyMongo.

Object structure in python:

```
obj = {
  field1: arrayOfArrays,
  field2: array
}
```

Mongo insert:

```
mongo.db.vectorPoints.insert_one(obj)
```

Structure arrayOfArrays:

```
[
  array([0.04234, -0.23523, 0,234....]), 
  array([0.04234, -0.23523, 0,234....]), ...
]
```

Structure array:

```
[0.04234, -0.23523, 0,234....]
```

Mongo insert_one throws an error regarding data format:

```
bson.errors.InvalidDocument: Cannot encode object: array([0.04234, -0.23523, 0,234....
```

How to format ´arrayOfArrays´ and ´array´ in order to allow the ´obj´ insertion to mongo?

Thanks for any advice facilitated.

Terminal print of arrayOfArrays:
[image]

Terminal print of array:
[image]

Terminal error on mongo insert:
[image]

Comment: Are those numpy arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert `array` to python builtin `list` type:

```
obj_to_insert = {
    'field1': [list(arr) for arr in obj['field1']],
    'field2': list(obj['field2'])    
}
```